# AngularJS fromJson returning string?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, angularjs, local-storage

I am experimenting with AngularJS's UI-Router for nested views, which seems to be working. However, in **line 97**, you will find a resolve, which delays the initialization of the nested view until the data is received and processed.

You will notice that I am capturing the json feed into localStorage (**line 123**). I am using this to save a copy of each post for fast data retrieval and UI binding instead of having to wait for a second Ajax request to retrieve that data.

### The Problem

If you click, any of the links returning from the ajax request, a nested view will appear. The data filling out of the view seems to have been converted to text, entirely. No HTML tag renders as HTML... one complete string.

### Diagnosis

I am not sure what is causing this. Could it be because I used jQuery Ajax call to retrieve that information?

I previously tried to use Angular's own [$http.jsonp](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#methods_jsonp) but I kept getting a type error that I just could NOT figure out... so maybe angular is good at only data "it" fetches?? I personally would like to ditch jQuery in this little app, but it seems to be the only option is is retrieving the data for me without problems.

### Request

Would like to have the data binded to the final nested view to render as HTML, and not as a string. Thanks!
**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/halkibsi/Z5aEs/11/**

### Note

This app 3rd level nested view does not show in Firefox, only worked in Chrome and Safari browsers. Did not test in IE or Opera.

```
    // LOAD MODULES
    angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.run([ '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
  }]);


    /*************************/
    // STATES
    /*************************/
    angular.module('myApp')
    .config( ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider ) {

    /***************************/
    // Redirects and Otherwise //
    $urlRouterProvider
        .when('/en', '/en/news')
        .otherwise('/');


    /************************/
    // State Configurations //
    $stateProvider

        /********/
        // HOME //
        /********/
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            template: 
                '<div>'+
                '<header class="section-title"><h1>HOME</h1></header>'+
                '<ul class="nav">'+
                '<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(\'arabic\') }"><a ui-sref="arabic">عربي</a></li>'+
                '<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(\'english\') }"><a ui-sref="english">English</a></li>'+
                '</ul>'+
                '</div>',
        })

        /**********/
        // ARABIC //
        /**********/
        .state('arabic', {
            url: '/ar',
            //abstract: true,
            template:
                '<div dir="rtl">'+
                    '<header class="section-title"><h1>الواجهة العربية</h1></header>'+
                    '<ul class="nav">'+
                        '<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(\'home\') }"><a ui-sref="home">الصفحة الرئيسية</a></li>'+
                        '<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(\'english\') }"><a ui-sref="english">English Interface</a></li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#/ar/ndc-news">أخبار</a></li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#/ar/ndc-photos">صور</a></li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#/ar/ndc-videos">فيديو</a></li>'+
                        '<li><a href="#/ar/ndc-podcasts">صوتيات</a></li>'+
                    '</ul>'+
                    '<!-- MAIN UI VIEW FOR THIS TEMPLATE -->'+
                    '<div ui-view ng-animate="{enter:\'fade-enter\'}"></div>'+
                '</div>',
        })

        /***********/
        // ENGLISH //
        /***********/
        .state('english', {
            //abstract: true,
            url: '/en',
            template:
                '<div>'+
                    '<header class="section-title"><h1>English Interface</h1></header>'+
                    '<ul class="nav">'+
                        '<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(\'home\') }"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>'+
                        '<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(\'arabic\') }"><a ui-sref="arabic">الواجهة العربية</a></li>'+
                        '<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(\'english.news\') }"><a ui-sref="english.news">News</a></li>'+
                        '<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(\'english.photos\') }"><a ui-sref="english.photos">Photos</a></li>'+
                        '<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(\'english.videos\') }"><a ui-sref="english.videos">Videos</a></li>'+
                        '<li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes(\'english.podcasts\') }"><a ui-sref="english.podcasts">Podcasts</a></li>'+
                    '</ul>'+
                    '<!-- MAIN UI VIEW FOR THIS TEMPLATE -->'+
                    '<div ui-view ng-animate="{enter:\'fade-enter\'}"></div>'+
                '</div>',
        })

            // English -> NDC News
            .state('english.news', {
                url: '/news',
                template:
                    '<header class="section-title"><h2>News</h2></header>'+
                    '<ul>'+
                      '<li ng-repeat="post in posts"><a ui-sref="english.news.single({postId:post.id})">{{ post.title }}</a></li>'+
                    '</ul>'+
                        '<div style="margin: 0 0 0 2em;">'+
                        '<!-- MAIN UI VIEW FOR THIS TEMPLATE -->'+
                        '<div class="ui-view-lev2" ui-view></div>'+
                    '</div>',
                resolve: {
                    news: function() {
                            return $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: "http://ndcye.org/api/get_posts/?post_type=post&cat=3&callback=?",
                                dataType: "jsonp",
                                success: function(response){
                                    //console.log(response);

                                    var newsList = [];
                                    for ( var i=0; i < response.posts.length; i++) {

                                        var id = response.posts[i].id;
                                        var title = response.posts[i].title;
                                        var thumbnail = response.posts[i].thumbnail_images.mobile.url;
                                        var excerpt = response.posts[i].excerpt;
                                        var content = response.posts[i].content;

                                        // SAVE POST AS AN OBJECT
                                        var post_object = {
                                            id: id,
                                            title: title,
                                            thumbnail: thumbnail,
                                            excerpt: excerpt,
                                            content: content,
                                        };
                                        if (localStorage.getItem( 'post_object_'+id ) === null) {
                                            localStorage.setItem( 'post_object_'+id, angular.toJson(post_object) );
                                        }

                                        newsList.push(post_object);
                                    }

                                    localStorage.setItem( 'ndc_news', angular.toJson(newsList) );
                                    console.log( newsList );
                                },
                                error: function(){
                                    console.log("error!");
                                }
                            });
                    }
                },
                controller: ['news', '$scope', '$state', function (news, $scope, $state) {
                    $scope.posts = news.posts;
                    console.log($scope.posts);
                }], // controller end
            })

                // English -> NDC News Single
                .state('english.news.single', {
                    url: '/{postId:[0-9]{1,4}}',
                    template:
                        '<header class="section-title"><h3>{{ singlePost.title }}</h3></header>'+
                        '<div>{{ singlePost.content }}</div>',
                    controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
                        var singlePost = '';
                        singlePost = angular.fromJson( localStorage.getItem( 'post_object_' + $stateParams.postId ) );

                        $scope.singlePost = singlePost;
                        console.log( singlePost );
                    }]
                })








            // English -> NDC Photos
            .state('english.photos', {
                url: '/photos',
                template:
                    '<header class="section-title"><h2>Photos</h2></header>'+
                    'Photo albums go here',
            })

            // English -> NDC Videos
            .state('english.videos', {
                url: '/videos',
                template:
                    '<header class="section-title"><h2>Videos</h2></header>'+
                    'YouTube playlists go here',
            })

            // English -> NDC Podcasts
            .state('english.podcasts', {
                url: '/podcasts',
                template:
                    '<header class="section-title"><h2>Podcasts</h2></header>'+
                    'Podcast playlists go here',
            })



  } // end function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider)

    ]) // end .CONFIG
    ; // ens STATES
```

Comment: demo works for me in jsfiddle. Might consider using a service to store your data and handle storage conversions. storage logic doesn't make sense to me

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my apologies for not explaining the logic behind using localStorage in this case. I intended to use factory services to create and update localStorage value of ajax results. However, I got stuck with this problem, and thus did not completely integrate localStorage in a way that would of made sense to you... but that was not what I was having trouble with. Thanks :)

Comment: +1 because this question is well written and very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two problems with the program:

1. You were using `{{ ... }}` to bind `singlePost.content` to HTML. This necessarily escapes the HTML
2. Merely using `ng-bind-html="singlePost.content"` will not work because angular now only renders [*trusted* HTML](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce).

The only changes needed were in the *state* `english.news.single`:

```js
.state('english.news.single', {
  url: '/{postId:[0-9]{1,4}}',
  template:
          '<header class="section-title"><h3>{{ singlePost.title }}</h3></header>'+
          '<div ng-bind-html="content"></div>',
  controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$sce', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $sce) {
          var singlePost = '';
          singlePost = angular.fromJson( localStorage.getItem( 'post_object_' + $stateParams.postId ) );

          $scope.singlePost = singlePost;
          $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(singlePost.content);
          console.log( singlePost );
  }]
})
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5aEs/12/

**Side note:** It works for me in Firefox 25 as well.

Comment: musically_ut... your solution was simply perfect, thanks!. I guess there is a lot more of AngularJS that I need to get a grasp on. BTW, you are correct that it works in FF25 in jsFiddle, but not on my local XAMPP server... weird.